# When to use an „als“ clause and when to use an „als ob“ clause?

Tags: meaning

> Es kommt mir vor, **als wäre** heute Sonntag.
>
> Es kommt mir vor, **als ob** heute Sonntag **wäre**.

Other than the fact that they follow different word order, are the two simply interchangeable? Or I wonder if there is some nuance involved.

I’m not sure when it is only allowed to use either of the two constructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the two are interchangeable, mean the same. The main differences are:

> - word order
> - number of words
> - sound

Which one to use is a question of your personal preference and feeling of style. I would prefer the first one because of its simplicity.

Both constructions – I think you know it – are called **Konjunktiv II**.
Here are some remarks about its **[usage](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktiv#Verwendung_des_Konjunktivs_II)**.

Comment: I tend to believe that "als ob" is used to indicate a fake, especially in the connection with the verb "tun", for instance: "Wir tun mal so, als ob das so gewollt wäre". I think in those cases one would not use simple "als".

Comment: @Alone-zee No, I mean that "tun, als ob" is indicating a fake. But in your example "tun" is in the subclause. I am talking of scenarios with "tun" in the main clause.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: With a sentence _»Wir tun, als wäre das gewollt«_ is nothing wrong at all.

Comment: @Pollitzer Yeah, it's not wrong. But I think "als ob" would be used to indicate / emphasize that it's a fake. But maybe my feeling is misleading me.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Hi. Is it just me, or in the following instance, does the "als" version refer to a **likely** scenario whereas the "als ob" version suggests that the speaker finds the situation **unbelievable**? "Es sieht so aus, **als** würde sie sich vollkommen erholen. {likely}" vs "Es sieht so aus, als ob sie sich vollkommen erholen würde. {unbelievable}"

Comment: @Alone-zee: _»als würde«_ and _»als ob ... würde«_ mean the same (in your example: _impression that she will recover completely_).